# Does this look like asbestos black mastic?

Tags: bathroom, tile, floor, asbestos

As I was lifting up a threshold strip / door bar under the bathroom door, I ended up damaging some tiles and lifting them, exposing what I believe might be asbestos black mastic.

However, after Googling what black mastic looks like - I’m not so sure. Does anyone know what this substance may be if it’s not black mastic?

In the meantime, I’ve ordered an asbestos kit and plan to check, but any advice here on what it may be would be much appreciated[image]

Thanks!

Comment: A simple bitumastic sealer?

Comment: Testing is the only way to know.  Looking at a picture the best you will get is an "yes, no, maybe" answer, together.  Age it was put down might limit the answer if it was recent.

Comment: Hi crip659, absolutely agree. However I was hoping to get some tips on what it may be if not black mastic, which it doesn’t look like compared to images I’ve found (typically looks much flatter, and shiny, whereas this is quite bulky and matt - like black concrete or something)

Comment: I believe the house was built between 1965-1980

Comment: If it's not shedding fibres it doesn't matter if it's asbestos or not.

Comment: That age puts it the in asbestos age as being possible.  If after that the possibility goes down quite fast.  Usually asbestos is dangerous only when in very tiny fibres/dust floating in the air that you can breath in, larger chunks are almost safe to be around.

Comment: The black mastic that contains asbestos is usually very thin, could it have been I doubt it there would normally have been asphalt tiles or vinyl that was glued down and even a 65 home the vinyl or tiles would still be there because by the time that flooring wore out or was encapsulated by the tile and thin set asbestos was a known danger and that flooring would not have been disturbed, that looks like thin set and it appears like a dark grout so with out testing I would say with the info provided it is not asbestos, maybe a sharper image would help and I have been in the trades since the 70’s